# association of resistors with short circuit

Tags: resistors, resistance

[image: How to simplify this?]

hi, a somewhat basic question: if i4 = 1, and all resistors have value R, what would be the voltage drop between a and b?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far to find the answer? EE.SE is not a free homework-solving website

Comment: Hint: R2, R3 and R4 are connected in parellel.

Comment: okay, so... I know I can associate R3 and R4 in parallel...

Comment: hi Bart, thanks for having a look. It would be much easier solving myself if I could, but I am really struggling. That is why I am asking help. I see I can associate R2 // R3, but I don't know where to connect the equivalent resistance...

Comment: In order to "fool" you, all these resistors have been drawn as if they're all in series. As suggested, some are actually in parallel. Try moving/rotating them around a bit in the schematic while keeping the connections the same of course. Then maybe it becomes more obvious how they're actually connected.

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here. Also, a dimensionless quantity for whatever you mean by "i" doesn't make any sense here.  Sloppiness with units is not tolerated here, as it probably isn't in your class either.  -1 for that, and the sloppy writing too.

Comment: One thing that beginners have trouble with when reading circuit diagrams is that the behavior of the circuit does not depend on **where** the components are drawn, but on **how** they are connected. So you have to look at the connections between the components, not their locations. That connection on the top connects one end of R2 and one end of R3 and one end of R4 together. Redraw the circuit so that that connection is obvious. Same thing for the connection on the bottom.

Comment: ah, ok, got it! so R2//R3//R4... I have then R/3 as equivalence... and thus total equivalence R5 + (R2//R3//R4) + R1 = 2R + R/3 = 7R/3 ... as the current divides itself in three on the (R2//R3//R4) association, the current from A to B is 3* I. So, the voltage drop between a and b is 7R/3 * 3 I = 7 R.

Comment: thank you so much everyone for taking your time! really much appreciated! I have indeed to crack my head more before asking for help!

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt made to solve are not what the site's about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @Bart said as a hint, R2, R3 and R4 are in parallel.
If you try to move the resistors and their connections to find an arrangement, you may get this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3d8ax.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, you should be able to apply Ohm's Law by yourself, I guess (I hope).

Comment: cool! I only visualized one parallel, after looking a bit more, I saw all 3 resistors were tied togetjer; thanks a lot for sharing the online circuit simulator!

Comment: It's a knife edge, answering homework questions that the OP hasn't shown any attempt to do or even shown any thinking on. Is it encouraging learning or encouraging future lazy OPs? Is it providing guidance or is it easy vote-chasing for those answering?

Comment: sorry, friends. Believe me, I have tried to do it before asking. Next time, I will post also my attempts.

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes. Next time, downvote **the question** before the answer.

Comment: Next time don't answer lazy homework questions. The question *was* downvoted, as deserved.  However, lazy homework questions shouldn't be answered, which is probably why you have accumulated 4 downvotes (currently).  It is really bad when people dump crap on us and walk away with the desired result.  Lots of people could have written your (rather obvious) answer.  The rest of them showed the proper restraint in not doing so, however.  You put your 2 minutes of glory ahead of the site, and got downvoted because of it.